# Visual Basic using tail on a specific file in a folder

Tags: vbscript, monitoring

I have a VB script that is running on a server, several times a day. One of the things this script is doing is creating log files, stating the status of certain files, determined by the age of the files. 
I do this by first finding the oldest and newest file, and if the newest file is within a specific timestamp(5 min) the status is “OK”, IF something in the check goes wrong the status is changed to “ERROR”
the status variable is string variable(should have been a Boolean, but that is for another day)

All this works properly, my issue is that before my scripts end I want it to take the last 10 lines from the newest file and write into the log file.

```
If IsNull(sNewestFile) Then
        status = "ERROR"
        objLogFile.writeLine "Directory: " & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & a_dirpath & vbCrLf & filespecstr & vbCrLf & "Status " & vbTab & vbTab & VbTab & VbTab & status & vbTab & vbTab & "No files found in directory."
        objLogFile.writeLine "Newest File: " & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & ""  & vbCrLf & "Alert Seconds " & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & a_seconds & vbCrLf &"Oldest File: "&vbTab & vbTab &vbTab
        objLogFile.writeline "Error Message: " & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "De 10 linjer fra Error loggen skal jo så være her." & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & status & vbTab & vbTab
    Else
        diff = DateDiff("s",dPrevDate,Now)
        If CLng(diff) > CLng(a_seconds) Then
            status = "ERROR"
            objLogFile.writeLine "Directory: " & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & a_dirpath & vbCrLf & filespecstr & vbCrLf & "Status " & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & status & vbTab & vbTab & "Newest file is to old."
            objLogFile.writeLine "Newest File: " & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & sNewestFile &vbTab& dPrevDate  & vbCrLf & "Alert Seconds " & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & a_seconds & vbCrLf &"Oldest File: "&vbTab & vbTab &vbTab & sOldestFile &vbTab& dOldPrevDate  & vbCrLf
            objLogFile.writeline "Error Message: " & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "De 10 linjer fra Error loggen skal jo så være her." & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & status & vbTab & vbTab              
        Else
            status = "OK"
            objLogFile.writeLine "Directory: " & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & a_dirpath & vbCrLf & filespecstr
            objLogFile.writeline "Status: " & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & status 
            objLogFile.writeline "Alert Seconds: " & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & a_seconds 
            objLogFile.writeLine "Newest File: " & vbCrLf & VbTab & sNewestFile & vbCrLf & VbTab & "TimeStamp: " & VbTab & VbTab & dPrevDate & vbCrLf
            objLogFile.writeline "Oldest File: "& vbCrLf & VbTab & sOldestFile & vbCrLf & VbTab & "TimeStamp: " & VbTab & VbTab & dOldPrevDate & vbCrLf 
        End If
    End if
Else
    status = "ERROR"
    objLogFile.writeLine "Directory: " & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & a_dirpath  & vbCrLf & "Status " & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & status & vbTab & vbTab & "Directory does not exist."
    objLogFile.writeLine "Newest File: " & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & ""  & vbCrLf & "Alert Seconds " & VbTab & VbTab & VbTab & a_seconds & vbCrLf &"Oldest File: "&vbTab & vbTab &vbTab &""
    LogError("The '"&a_dirpath &"' does not exist. The directory will not be checked." )
End If
```

So here I am wrritting to the log file depending on the status.

What I know what is something like

```
Try
    if(status = "ERROR") then
        'It is the NewestFile I want to run TAIL.exe on to get the last 10 lines of text.
        'how do I do this?

    End if
    if (status = "ERROR") then
    objLogFile.writeline "Error Message: " & vbCrLf & 
'Using a string variable with the 10 lines of code
    else
        objLogFile.writeline "Error Message: No error has been detected."
    End If  
End Try
```

The question is I have the tail.exe from http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ but I am unsure how to call this on that specific file. the tail.exe file will be in the same folder as the script.

I've been looking to : http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Runing-an-executable-file-from-VBScript-m22.aspx for help but didnt work for me.

Comment: So I have just tried with a simple command 

`errorStr = tail -n10 sNewestFile`

But that just ended with a "Expected end of statement" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
errorStr = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec( _ 
               "tail -n 10 """ & sNewestFile & """" _ 
           ).StdOut.ReadAll
```

Or, if it is needed to execute the `tail.exe` located in the script folder

```
With WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    tail = .BuildPath(.GetFile(WScript.ScriptFullName).ParentFolder.Path, "tail.exe")
End With 

errorStr = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec( _ 
               """" & tail & """ -n 10 """ & sNewestFile & """" _ 
           ).StdOut.ReadAll
```

Comment: And the tail.exe file lays with in the same folder as the Script correct ?

Comment: This was the solution to the problem.

Comment: @Jesper, I've been a little slow. Anyway, just in case your code needs to change the current active directory (where the `tail.exe` will be looked for), I've included the code needed to locate the script folder and call the executable stored inside it.

Comment: So the first piece of code just assumes that  the Tail file is laying inside the same folder as the Script?
The second piece looks in the parent folder of the script folder for the file called tail.exe?

`.StdOut.ReadAll` 
This piece of code, does that just say that it has to read the entire folder or the entire file?

Comment: @Jesper, first code assumes that `tail.exe` can be found. It should be in the *current active directory* or anywhere in the `path`. Second code indicates the full path to the tool, joining the `tail.exe` literal and the full path of the folder containing the current script (its parent folder from the point of view of the script). The `ReadAll` method is from the `StdOut` stream of the `WshShell` object. It will *Read All* the output of the executed command, not the folder nor the file.